# Listview selects mutliple items when clicked

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to make a task manager, and I only have one problem. I have a listview that gets inflated. All the elements in the listview are correct. The problem is that when I select an item, the listview will select another item  away. I've heard listviews repopulate the list as it scrolls down to save memory. I think this may be some sort of problem. Here is a picture of the [**problem**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spCoH.jpg). 
    If i had more apps loaded, then it would continue to select multiple at once.

Here is the code of my adapter and activity and XML associated

```
public class TaskAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private List<TaskInfo> mListAppInfo;
private PackageManager mPack;


public TaskAdapter(Context c, List<TaskInfo> list, PackageManager pack) {
    mContext = c;
    mListAppInfo = list;
    mPack = pack;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListAppInfo.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mListAppInfo.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TaskInfo entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);


    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        //System.out.println("Setting LayoutInflater in TaskAdapter " +mContext +" " +R.layout.taskinfo +" " +R.id.tmbox);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taskinfo,null);
    }

        ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tmImage);
        ivIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.getIcon());

        TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tmbox);
        tvName.setText(entry.getName());

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.tmbox);
                if(v.isSelected())
                {
                    System.out.println("Listview not selected ");
                    //CK.get(arg2).setChecked(false);
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    v.setSelected(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Listview selected ");
                    //CK.get(arg2).setChecked(true);
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    v.setSelected(true);
                }

            }
        });

    return convertView;




public class TaskManager extends Activity implements Runnable
    {
private ProgressDialog pd;
private TextView ram;
private String s;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.taskpage);
        setTitleColor(Color.YELLOW);

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        //System.out.println("In Taskmanager Run() Thread");
        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        final ListView box = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cBoxSpace);
        final List<TaskInfo> CK = populate(box, pm);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                ram.setText(s);
                box.setAdapter(new TaskAdapter(TaskManager.this, CK, pm));

                //System.out.println("In Taskmanager runnable Run()");    
                endChecked(CK);
            }
        });
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
```

Taskinfo.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/tmImage"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/tmbox"
    android:lines="2"/>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Taskpage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cBoxSpace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/RAM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/endButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="End Selected Tasks" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas for what reason mutliple items are selected with a single click would be GREATLY appreciated. I've been messing around with different implementations and listeners and listadapters but to no avail.

Comment: When multiple items are selected, do the multiple selections occur with items visible on the screen or only upon scrolling?

Comment: Sorry didnt mean to edit your post, meant to edit mine >.<  I explained the answer in the edit

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is you only save checking state in the view(v.setSelected).

And you reuse these view, so its checkbox is always not change its state.

You can create a state array to save every checking state of every TaskInfo, and check this array when you create a view.

for example

```
// default is false
ArrayList<Boolean> checkingStates = new ArrayList<Boolean>(mListAppInfo.size());
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TaskInfo entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taskinfo,null);
    }

    ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tmImage);
    ivIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.getIcon());

    TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tmbox);
    tvName.setText(entry.getName());

    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.tmbox);
    checkBox.setChecked(checkingStates.get(position));
    convertView.setSelected(checkingStates.get(position));

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.isSelected())
            {
                System.out.println("Listview not selected ");
                //CK.get(arg2).setChecked(false);
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
                v.setSelected(false);
                checkingStates.get(position) = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Listview selected ");
                //CK.get(arg2).setChecked(true);
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                v.setSelected(true);
                checkingStates.get(position) = true;
            }

        }
    });

return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but part of your problem might be related to the condition in your `onClick` method:

```
if(v.isSelected())
```

I think you want that to read

```
if(v.isChecked())
```

`isSelected` is inherited from View, and it means something different from `isChecked`

Also, the whether the CheckBox is checked or not is independent from your data model since it is a recycled view. Your CheckBox should be checked based on `entry` (I'm assuming your `TextInfo` class has an `isChecked()` method that returns a boolean:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TaskInfo entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        //System.out.println("Setting LayoutInflater in TaskAdapter " +mContext +" " +R.layout.taskinfo +" " +R.id.tmbox);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taskinfo,null);
    }

    ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tmImage);
    ivIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.getIcon());

    TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tmbox);
    tvName.setText(entry.getName());

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.tmbox);
    checkBox.setChecked(entry.isChecked());
}
```

I don't think you need the `View.OnClickListener` you are attaching to `convertView`. You should handle that in the `OnItemClickListener` attached to the `ListView`. Assuming your `ListView` is called `listView` and `TaskInfo` instances have `setChecked` and `isChecked` methods:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);
        entry.setChecked(!entry.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't set the list checked or unchecked on view position.
because view position means only visible items position in your listview but you would like to set checked or uncheked status on a particular list item.

That's why this problem arises in your code.

You have the need to set the items checked and unchecked on your custom arraylist getter setter like the code i have attached below:

```
package com.app.adapter;



public class CategoryDynamicAdapter {

    public static ArrayList<CategoryBean> categoryList = new ArrayList<CategoryBean>();

    Context context;
    Typeface typeface;
    public static String videoUrl = "" ;    
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;


      // constructor
      public CategoryDynamicAdapter(Activity a, Context context, Bitmap [] imagelist,ArrayList<CategoryBean> list) {

        this.context    = context;
        this.categoryList       = list;
        this.a = a;


    }

     // Baseadapter to the set the data response from web service into listview.
     public BaseAdapter mEventAdapter  = new BaseAdapter() {



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return categoryList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return categoryList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView    title,category,uploadedBy;
            ImageView   image;
            RatingBar video_rating;
            Button  report_video ,Flag_video;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder  vh = null ;

                if(convertView  ==  null) {

                vh                    =         new                                                          ViewHolder();  
                convertView           =         LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate (R .layout.custom_category_list_layout,null,false);
                vh.title              =         (TextView)                convertView                .findViewById        (R.id.title);
                vh.image = (ImageView)          convertView.findViewById(R.id.Imagefield);

                convertView.setTag(vh);
            }
            else 
            {
                vh=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }   

            try
            {
                final CategoryBean Cb = categoryList.get(position);


//pay attention to code below this line i have shown here how to select a listview using arraylist getter setter objects 

                String checkedStatus   =   Cb.getCheckedStringStaus();
            if(checkdStatus.equal("0")
              { 
                   System.out.println("Listview not selected ");
                    //CK.get(arg2).setChecked(false);
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    v.setSelected(false);
              }
                else             ////checkdStatus.equal("1")
                {
                    System.out.println("Listview selected ");
                    //CK.get(arg2).setChecked(true);
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    v.setSelected(true);
                }

            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```